# Is it correct to say "My sense of taste got changed when I have Covid 19"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Currently, I have Covid 19.

On the day I started to feel the symptom, I ate some braised meat in the afternoon and it tasted ok, but on the evening of the same day, the same braised meat tasted really salty.

Normally, "**I lost my sense of taste**" is a common phrase on the internet but this sentence can not be applied in my case because I didn't lose my sense of taste. It is just that now food, which I eat, tastes different from it did.

Is it correct to say "**My sense of taste got changed when I have Covid 19**"?

Comment: Asking for proofreading is off-topic. What exactly about the sentence do you have doubts about? What aspect of it did you research? What did that research tell you? For example, are you unsure about the *tense* of some of the verbs? If you could bring that into the question, it might qualify.

Comment: If you simply remove slangy/informal ***got***, your text is (almost) fine. It's a bit *less* slangy in constructions using preposition ***by*** (explicitly referencing a ***cause***, whereas your ***when*** simply indicates ***at that time***). So *My sense of taste got changed **by** Covid 19* is a bit less slangy. But it should really be *My sense of taste **was** changed **by** Covid 19* (the normal / "correct" auxiliary verb) OR *My sense of taste changed when I had Covid 19* (no auxiliary verb at all before ***changed***). But as it stands the question looks like proofreading to me.

Comment: Believe me, "got changed" sounds really awful.  We say: My x **changed**  when I got Covid 19. get rich, get poor, get sick, and many others but not get changed EXCEPT: He went to the locker room to get changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most natural way would probably be "my sense of taste **changed**" or maybe "my sense of taste **was changed**." "My sense of taste got changed **by** COVID 19" sounds fine as well, but outside of this construction (and "to get changed" meaning "to change clothes"), "got changed" isn't used in standard English.

Also, saying "when I **have**" feels wrong. You lost your taste in the past, so the description for when it happened should be in the past as well. Saying "when I **had** COVID" means you had COVID in the past, which normally implies that you don't have COVID anymore. So if you still have COVID, the most natural way is probably "when I **got** COVID", implying that losing your taste was one of the symptoms that began when you first got the virus. (Or, if you want to be formal, you could use "caught" instead of "got" for the same meaning.)